# Jasmine typescript - issue with testing func vs let item = func

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to Test a function in jasmine that is defined like this:

```
let main =  new function() {
    this.addIframe = () => {
        try {
            $("body").append("<iframe id='myiframe'> </iframe>");
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            dosomthing();
            return false;
        }
    };
};
```

I need this type of definition to later on set up spies and stuff like that in the test suit. But right now im stuck with an issue when trying to test the return statment using this code:

```
  describe("Function AddIframe", ()=> {
    it("should return true if opened iframe",()=>{
        expect(addIframe()).toBe(true);
   });
```

The issue is i get Undefined, now i understand that it is becouse the way js work, with the 2 step run.

I tried moving to a function(){} defintion but  i need that for my other test. 
I test the idea of putting it inside an object but still gets undefined even when using this.method.

Can any one tell me what am i missing here or how i can bypass this issue?

Comment: I am not sure if this will be helpfull for anyone but what made this issue for me was that before that check there was an already defined spy for the function i tested. so i just moved the tests up, not the smothest of soultions but fixed the current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `addIframe` is defined on the `main` object because you are creating a new instance of the anonymous constructor function. So you have to use `main.addIframe()` instead of `addIframe()`:

```
expect(main.addIframe()).toBe(true);
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bBL9P/508/